# How to make validation for Input?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making simple app, where user have an opportunity to find movie (with OMDB API). So I did it. But when I enter a non-existent movie, i have an undefined map error . And This is logical, because an array with such data does not exist. How to make validation to notify the user of an error.

**Search function**

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    s: '',
    response: [],
    selected: {}
  });

  const apiURL = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=73f30b51'

  const searchFilm = e => {
    if(e.key === 'Enter'){
      axios(apiURL + "&s=" + state.s).then(({data}) => {
        let response = data.Search;
        setState(prevState => {
          return  {...prevState, response: []},
                  {...prevState, response: response}
        })
      })
    } 
  }
```

**Filter** (*map error*)

```
const Result = ({response,openCurrentMovie}) => {
    return(
        <div className="results">
            {response.map(result => (
            <Movie key={result.imdbID} result={result} openCurrentMovie={openCurrentMovie}/>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if there is something in `response` in your render function:

```
const Result = ({response,openCurrentMovie}) => {
    if (!response) return <div>Sorry bro, no movie found</div>
    return(
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if `response = data.Search;` is undefined, you can set an error state, and use it to render a message to your user.

```
const [error, setError] = useState(null); // use error value to render a component to show error

 const searchFilm = e => {
    if(e.key === 'Enter'){
      axios(apiURL + "&s=" + state.s).then(({data}) => {
        let response = data.Search;
        if(!response){
           setError(true) // setting the error as true. You can give some specific message as well
        }
        setState(prevState => {
          return {...prevState, response: response}
        })
      })
    } 
  }
```